# Convert a string to integer, adding one with zero before it?

Tags: php, string, numbers, type-conversion

I have strings with data that represent a month. For example "00" is January, "01" is February, "02" is March and so on. 
How do I make the string represent like this "01" is January, "02" is February and so on, an easier way. I couldn't find any PHP function that did the trick.

/* 
Type cast month to int, if less than one digit add a zero and convert to string
elseif more than 9(2 digits) convert to string
*/

```
$month = "00"; // represents January
$month = (int) $month;
$month += 1;

if ($month <= 9){
    $month = str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
elseif ($month > 9){
    $month = (string) $month; 
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using str_pad you can also use sprintf:

```
$month = "00";
$month = (int) $month;
$month += 1;
$month = sprintf("%02s", $month);
```

Or, even shorter:

```
$month = sprintf("%02s", $month + 1);
```

Comment: I really like this answer, read the php documentation about this function, but can't understand it 100%, the first param is a bit confusing for me, thanks though :)

Comment: I'm not too good at PHP but the `%` should start the format string,

Comment: I'm not too good at PHP. From right to left this should read: This is a string (s) with a width of 2 characters; if there's only one character (i.e. <10), pad/fill with "0".  The `%` starts the format string. I think the format is similar to the C function sprintf: [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm) Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks explaining it clearly, I wasn't sure about the 0, it helpt :)

Answer (score 1):

Your way is pretty much the simplest option, but you don't need to check for the size of the month, str_pad does it for you.

```
$month = "00"; // represents January
$month = (int) $month;
$month += 1;
$month = str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$month = "00"; // represents January

// just increment the string value
// comment out the to display the different months
$month++; 
$month++;
$month++;
$month++;
$month++;
$month++;
$month++;
$month++;
$month++;
$month++;
$month++;
$month++;

// Month = 13 when un-commenting, but should return 01
// $month++;


$month = ($month > 12) ? "01": str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

echo "Month: {$month}\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you mean:

```
switch($monthString)
{
case "January": $monthInt = "00";
break;
case "Febuary": $monthInt = "01";
break;
case "March": $monthInt = "02";
break;
case "April": $monthInt = "03";
break;
...
}
```